# Json back slashes

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api project and a controller receives a Json parameter like this

```
 public HttpResponseMessage QueryRead([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request, string queryparams, int qryId)
```

The string queryparams is actually a Json object that the client sends in the form

```
"{\"Supplier\":{\"name\":\"Supplier\",\"type\":\"PK\",\"textvalue\":\"[{\"Supplier_Key\":2,\"Supplier_Value\":\"Foxes Beverages \"}]\",\"value\":\"[2]\"}}"
```

This is a valid json object.
The problem is that the string queryparams removes all backslashes and the string becomes

```
{"Supplier":{"name":"Supplier","type":"PK","textvalue":"[{"Supplier_Key":2,"Supplier_Value":"Foxes Beverages "}]","value":"[2]"}}
```

It ommits all backslashes and the later is not a valid json

Any ideas?

Comment: The latter looks like a valid JSON object to me. It's not a JSON *string*, that's all.

Comment: Try to validate these 2 json using http://jsonlint.com/ You will see that the second is not valid

Comment: Is a valid JSON, the back slashed are used to avoid end of string with doublequotes

Comment: Or rather, it's a valid JSON object apart from the `textvalue` part... which is basically broken. The client is presumably sending you a string which is meant to be a string which can be parsed as JSON. The backslashes are escapes required by JSON to represent that text - but the text itself *isn't* valid JSON. The client appears to be broken here.

Comment: *"This is a valid json object"* No, it's a valid JSON **string**. A single value. Somewhere you're taking something that's already been turned into a JSON string and then encoding it as JSON a *second* time. Don't do that. :-)

Comment: Array should not be in quotes, check with this : "textvalue":[{"Supplier_Key":2,"Supplier_Value":"Foxes Beverages "}]

Comment: I thought the purpose of JSON was a standardised way of transferring arrays between systems by creating/using a web API? If so, there shouldn't be any reason to create it manually.

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis: Where did you get the text you've quoted as an example of what the client sent you? Because it's **really** weird. Did you hand-edit the `textvalue` part when posting the question?

Comment: It's data that the client sends me using Kendo multiselect tool

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis: Where did you get the text you've quoted as an example of what the client sent you? E.g., was it from a browser console, an error log, a debugger, wireshark, ...

Answer (score 1):

If your client is **really** sending you

```
"{\"Supplier\":{\"name\":\"Supplier\",\"type\":\"PK\",\"textvalue\":\"[{\"Supplier_Key\":2,\"Supplier_Value\":\"Foxes Beverages \"}]\",\"value\":\"[2]\"}}"
```

...the trouble is at the client end. It looks like double-encoded JSON, as though they'd done this (in JavaScript):

```
var json = JSON.stringify(originalObject);
var json2 = JSON.stringify(json);
```

...but the `textvalue` part is wrong even for double-encoded JSON, so it's not that simple. So if (again) they're **really** sending that to you, the problem is at their end. Moreover, you can't correct it. If it were "just" double-encoded JSON, you could correct for it by parsing it twice. But it isn't, because of the value of `textvalue`, so it's nonsense (if it's really like that).